# Python: How to translate UTF8 String containing unicode decoded characters ("Ok\u00c9" to "Oké")

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, encoding, decoding

I'm trying to fix the string I'm getting from my python script.

I'm doing a call to an API, but it is returning me utf8 String that is still containing unicode encoded characters.

stuff like "Ok\u00c9" should be "Oké".

I tried converting it, but all efforts to fix it seem to result in errors or in the same result. is there someone who could fix this for me in Python 3?

```
print('\u00c9'.encode().decode('unicode-escape'))
>> é
print('Ok\u00c9'.encode().decode('unicode-escape'))
>> should print 'Oké'
>> but gives an error
```

hope you guys know the solution. thanks in advance!

Comment: `print('Ok\u00c9')` works for me.  What is the actual error that you see?

Comment: `\u00c9` is just a _representation_ used in JSON transfers in case the response is handled by a server that can't handle unicode.  It shouldn't need any special handling once it reaches your python code.

Comment: You probably mean `"OK\\u00c9"` (length 8) which contains a *literal* backslash.  `"OK\u00c9"` is an escape code but the string is length 3 and when printed with show `'Oké'`. Please clarify.  If you are receiving a JSON response use `json.loads` to translate it.

Comment: `'\u00c9'` is a string literal of Python, with escape sequence. When Python reads the source, it immediately substitute the `\u00c9` with the relevant codepoint. At run time (so when python execute encode/decode, it already lost the original string. If you do not want escapes on string literals, use the *raw* strings: `r'\u00c9'`. Note: never use "encode() without argument. Which encoding should be used? It depends on operating system, and so you may get surprises. Better to be explicit.

Comment: In short: a `'\u00c9'` in code is not equal `'\u00c9'` in a string, so it is not the best way to test encoding/decoding.

Comment: thanks for all the comments! if i try to run what @snakecharmerb runs it prints "Ok�" in the console. seems like it might be a problem in my IDE then? I'm using Visual studio code in utf8 encoding. might that be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive found the problem. The encoding decoding was wrong. The text came in as Windows-1252 encoding.

I've use

```
import chardet
chardet.detect(var3.encode())
```

to detect the proper encoding, and the did a

```
var3 = 'OK\u00c9'.encode('utf8').decode('Windows-1252').encode('utf8').decode('utf8')
```

conversion to eventually get it in the right format!